How to build the antlr grammar provided?
I would like to build a cpp parser using cpp and I'm using ANTLR4. I notice there is this 'grammar' section from the official github antlr grammar github and I've downloaded it. While opening the CPP file inside, I notice there is a CPP14Parser and a CPP14Lexer, also there's another CPP file with a CPPParser in it. I've been running through the documentations for days but it seems it was outdated. I've tried running antlr-4 but later I kept getting and error when trying to compile it. However, the CMakeLists.txt and main(basically all other file) I wrote does work on an older version where things are more clean The version I successfully build. Can somene please teach me how to build the latest version of current grammar? Please let me know if any more specific context is needed! Thanks in advance!
Edit:
The step I did was listed as below, I install the older version of CPP14.g4(as written in above description), and wrote my wrote my own CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(CPPparser)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
include_directories(
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generated/
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cppruntime/src/
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/
)
set(src_dir
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generated/CPP14Lexer.cpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generated/CPP14Parser.cpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generated/CPP14Visitor.cpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generated/CPP14BaseVisitor.cpp
 )
file(GLOB antlr4-cpp-src
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cppruntime/src/*.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cppruntime/src/atn/*.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cppruntime/src/dfa/*.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cppruntime/src/internal/*.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cppruntime/src/misc/*.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cppruntime/src/support/*.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cppruntime/src/tree/*.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cppruntime/src/tree/pattern/*.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cppruntime/src/tree/xpath/*.cpp
)
add_library (antlr4-cpp-runtime ${antlr4-cpp-src})
add_executable(CPPparser ${src_dir} src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(CPPparser antlr4-cpp-runtime)

and I have the main.cpp written in a /src folder, /generated having the files generated after I run antlr4 -Dlanguage=Cpp -visitor, /cppruntime for the runtime from the official antlr github. So I'll run the following command on a ubuntu
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make

It does work perfectly fine, however, when I try to compile the latest file provided on github using the same steps, I get tons of error when running the make command.
The error are as lited below
: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
   12 | class  CPP14Parser : public CPP14ParserBase {
      |                                             ^
/home/user/CPnew/generated/CPP14Parser.h:118:3: error: ‘CPP14Parser::~CPP14Parser()’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
  118 |   ~CPP14Parser() override;
      |   ^
/home/user/CPnew/generated/CPP14Parser.h:120:15: error: ‘std::string CPP14Parser::getGrammarFileName() const’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
  120 |   std::string getGrammarFileName() const override;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/CPnew/generated/CPP14Parser.h:122:27: error: ‘const antlr4::atn::ATN& CPP14Parser::getATN() const’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
  122 |   const antlr4::atn::ATN& getATN() const override;
      |                           ^~~~~~
/home/user/CPnew/generated/CPP14Parser.h:124:35: error: ‘const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >& CPP14Parser::getRuleNames() const’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
  124 |   const std::vector<std::string>& getRuleNames() const override;
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/CPnew/generated/CPP14Parser.h:126:34: error: ‘const antlr4::dfa::Vocabulary& CPP14Parser::getVocabulary() const’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
  126 |   const antlr4::dfa::Vocabulary& getVocabulary() const override;
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/CPnew/generated/CPP14Parser.h:128:34: error: ‘antlr4::atn::SerializedATNView CPP14Parser::getSerializedATN() const’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
  128 |   antlr4::atn::SerializedATNView getSerializedATN() const override;
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/CPnew/generated/CPP14Parser.h:3895:8: error: ‘bool CPP14Parser::sempred(antlr4::RuleContext*, size_t, size_t)’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
 3895 |   bool sempred(antlr4::RuleContext *_localctx, size_t ruleIndex, size_t predicateIndex) override;
      |        ^~~~~~~
/home/user/CPnew/cppruntime/src/CPP14ParserBase.cpp:5:6: error: ‘CPP14ParserBase’ has not been declared
    5 | bool CPP14ParserBase::IsPureSpecifierAllowed()
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/CPnew/cppruntime/src/CPP14ParserBase.cpp: In function ‘bool IsPureSpecifierAllowed()’:
/home/user/CPnew/cppruntime/src/CPP14ParserBase.cpp:9:18: error: invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function
    9 |         auto x = this->getRuleContext(); // memberDeclarator
      |                  ^~~~

In case needed,my main.cpp is as below
#include <iostream>
#include "CPP14Lexer.h"
#include "CPP14Parser.h"
using namespace antlr4;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    const char* filepath = argv[1];
    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(filepath);
    ANTLRInputStream input(ifs);

    CPP14Lexer lexer(&input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);

    CPP14Parser parser(&tokens);
    tree::ParseTree* tree = parser.translationunit();

    if (parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() > 0) {
        std::cout<<"File syntax error"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    tokens.fill();
    for (auto t : tokens.getTokens()) {
        std::cout<<t->toString()<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << tree->toStringTree(&parser) << std::endl << std::endl;


    ifs.close();
    return 0;
}

TLDR:If possible, please guide me on how to build the latest version of antlr grammar.
Sorry if I'm not making things clear or making any sily mistake, it's my first question here.

Please edit your question with the exact steps you tried and what error messages you got. "please guide me" is not an actionable question.

Keep in mind that although the grammars are hosted on the official Github repository of the ANTLR project, all grammars are user contributions. Many (most?) of them are not very well tested.

@Botje Alright, I've done the editing, sorry for the inappropriate question format, thanks for reminding!

@BartKiers does that mean I should be expecting that it might not actually work and just use an older version of it?

I found CPP14ParserBase.h and .cpp file just sitting in the repository Did you forget to download them?

The grammars are tested very well, for three different OSes and many of the targets. But you must always check the desc.xml to see if the target you want is listed.

@Botje that's actually my question, I do notice them but I actually didn't knew what to do with them as the demo and other related documentation provided seems to be outdated (which I don't find any relevant info on the net as well)

@kaby76 alright! I saw your answer and will test it out real soon, thanks for the help provided!

"The grammars are tested very well", sure, grammars include various input sources which are tested upon a build, but most of them do not include odd corner cases of the language that are being parsed. Nor is the structure of the parse tree checked to test if the parse tree is "correct". It is my experience that when I use a grammar from the "official" repo, it often needs quite a bit of tweaking to get is right. Just my 2 cents. It also depends on the popularity of the grammar: perhaps the CPP and various SQL grammars are of a better quality than others.

True. Testing across targets is done well. I have spent years cleaning this up, pointing out Antlr4 bugs across runtimes, etc. Testing across syntax is poor because the test cases are provided by the developer of the grammar. In some grammars (e.g., yara), there is only one test. A measure of parser-rule grammar tested as percentile is performed per PR using trcover. There is no CI testing across parser tracing. The closest for that is parse tree testing, which is for only a few cases.

Step 1 -- clone the repo
$ git clone https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4.git
Cloning into 'grammars-v4'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 50618, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1907/1907), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1285/1285), done.
remote: Total 50618 (delta 686), reused 1618 (delta 510), pack-reused 48711
Receiving objects: 100% (50618/50618), 47.50 MiB | 23.79 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (27107/27107), done.
Updating files: 100% (9413/9413), done.

Step 2 -- navigate to cpp and check desc.xml to see if target is available for grammar
$ cd grammars-v4/cpp/
$ cat desc.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<desc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../_scripts/desc.xsd">
   <targets>Cpp;CSharp;Dart;Go;Java;JavaScript;Python3;Antlr4ng</targets>
</desc>

The desc.xml describes what targets build and are "working". It is sometimes possible to see target files available for a target, but they may not build, or the grammar is too slow to use in practice.
For the cpp grammar, the Cpp target is listed, so the target "works".
Step 3 -- copy target support files into directory containing grammar
$ cp Cpp/* .

You have to copy the files to the directory. Otherwise, you will get compilation errors.
Step 4 -- transform the grammar using the Python script provided
$ python transformGrammar.py
Altering .\CPP14Lexer.g4
Writing ...
Altering .\CPP14Parser.g4
Writing ...

The grammar contains "actions", which is target-specific code, specifically for Java. You must convert this. to the syntax for C++, this->.
$ grep this *.g4
CPP14Lexer.g4:This: 'this';
CPP14Parser.g4: * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and
CPP14Parser.g4: * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or
CPP14Parser.g4:        | { this->IsPureSpecifierAllowed() }? pureSpecifier
CPP14Parser.g4:        | { this->IsPureSpecifierAllowed() }? virtualSpecifierSeq pureSpecifier

Step 5 -- write a driver and build script for the grammar
The grammar in the repo contains just the grammar. It does not contain any driver code because people want to package the parser in a number of different ways. You need to write this code yourself. In addition, you need a build script to do a build in a repeatable, error-free way. This is why people use CMake.
In lieu of that, you can run the following commands to get the code to compile. You will still need to write the driver, decide how you want to package and link the Antlr Cpp runtime (static vs dynamic libraries, etc).
a) Clone the antlr4 repo
pushd ../../
$ git clone https://github.com/antlr/antlr4.git
Cloning into 'antlr4'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 134889, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (158/158), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (82/82), done.
remote: Total 134889 (delta 62), reused 110 (delta 47), pack-reused 134731
Receiving objects: 100% (134889/134889), 68.26 MiB | 23.52 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (79495/79495), done.
Updating files: 100% (2273/2273), done.
$ popd

b) Run antlr4 tool to generate the parser source code
$ antlr4 -Dlanguage=Cpp CPP14Lexer.g4 CPP14Parser.g4

c) Compile using GNU compiler
$ g++ -std='c++17' -pthread -c -I../../antlr4/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/ -g *.cpp

